# Swift control flow: Unwrapping nil despite if check?

Tags: swift

This sounds like a programming-newbie-question but how is this situation possible?

[image]

```
for typelessResultDict in results {
    let resultDict = typelessResultDict as! Dictionary<String, Any>
    let internalId = resultDict["internalId"] as? String?
    let orderDate = resultDict["orderDate"] as? Date?
    
    if internalId == nil || orderDate == nil {
        #if DEBUG
        fatalError("internalId/orderDate was nil")
        #endif
        continue
    }
    do {
        try removeAllButOne(internalId: internalId!!, orderDate: orderDate!!)
    } catch {
        LOGGER.error("Could not deduplicate.")
    }
}
```

In a `for` loop, I am explicitly checking `if` the variable `orderDate` is `nil` and either raise a `fatalError` in DEBUG or at least `continue` the loop, effectively canceling all other statements.

However, you can see that my code is executed and raises a fatal error because of force-unwrapping `nil` a few lines later.

Is this a bug or do I need to revisit first semester computer science?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the types of `internalId` and `orderDate` are double optionals - `String??` and `Date??` respectively. This happens because `resultDict["internalId"]` produces a `Any?` (the key could be absent in the dictionary), and the safe cast to `String?` produces a `String??`, as there are 3 cases:

- the key is present in the dictionary, and the cast succeeds (both layers of optional would be non-nil)
- the key is absent in the dictionary (the outer optional would be non-nil, wrapping a `nil` as the inner optional)
- the cast fails (the outer optional is nil)

`== nil` only checks if the outermost layer of the optional is nil, but you are unwrapping both layers with two exclamation marks. The first exclamation mark is safe as ensured by your if statement, but the second is not.

You can avoid all of this if you just cast to `String` and `Date` instead:

```
let internalId = resultDict["internalId"] as? String
let orderDate = resultDict["orderDate"] as? Date
```

You can also use a `guard` statement to eliminate the forced unwrapping:

```
guard let internalId = resultDict["internalId"] as? String,
      let orderDate = resultDict["orderDate"] as? Date else {
    #if DEBUG
    fatalError("internalId/orderDate was nil")
    #endif
    continue
}

do {
    try removeAllButOne(internalId: internalId, orderDate: orderDate)
} catch {
    LOGGER.error("Could not deduplicate.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I feel this is a weakness in the language design as I would have expected that == nil considers all "optional" layers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is using 'as? String?' and 'as? Date?' that means your internalId and orderDate object types are :

String?? and Date??

They are like a box that eventually can contain an optional, that is another box.
So when you check :

```
if internalId == nil || orderDate == nil
```

The answer is always false, because they really contains an optional object. Regardless of whether the optional si full or empty.

So instead of 'as? String?' you can use :

- as? String

Now your code will work.

I suggest you this syntax that is more clear :

```
let resultDict : [String : Any] = [:]
let internalDict = resultDict["InternalDict"] as? String
let orderDate = resultDict["OrderDate"] as? Date

if let internalDict = internalDict, let orderDate = orderDate
{
    //They are not Nil
    print(internalDict)
    print(orderDate)
}
else
{
    //One of them is Nil
    fatalError("internalDict/orderDate was nil")
}
```

P.S. Please next time post text and not image.